# Quasi-Fermi levels, can this condition be false?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

Let $E_{FV}$ be the Quasi-Fermi level of the valance band, $E_{FC}$ be the Quasi-Fermi level of the conduction band and $E_g$ be the band gap (the energy difference between valance and conduction band).

On my book it is written that, in order to achieve the condition $E_{FC}-E_{FV}\ge E_g$, in a semiconductor, we need to raise enough electron in the conduction band.

But to me it looks like this condition is always true because the minimum value of $E_{FC}-E_{FV}$ is exactly $E_g$. Can you explain in which situation this condition isn't satisfied?

Comment: As far as I understand, the quasi Fermi energy levels arise only when the semiconductor is not in equilibrium. At equilibrium, the $E_{FC}$ and $E_{FV}$ are exactl the same and $E_{FC}-E_{FV}=0$ irrespective of temperature. So the statement "at T=0K the minimum value of EFC−EFV is exactly Eg" seems to be erroneous.

Comment: yes, thank you for the observation. I edited the question